# CUDA batch copy images

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I have a 5000+ images in a directory. I want to perform image comparison between two images. Total no of comparisons for 5000 images becomes <sup>5000</sup>C<sub>2</sub> = 12,497,500.
I am using OpenCV with CUDA 10.1 but it is slower than without CUDA. In my understanding, host to device and vice-versa transfer is a bottleneck here.

Is it possible to transfer images in a batch of 100 Array of images and finally get the resultant in one shot?

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to gain from using CUDA?

Comment: As mentioned, I want to reduce the time consumption for NxN image comparisons by copying all images in batch to device memory

Comment: You can read about streams and how to utilize them to overlap computation and memory transfer: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/how-overlap-data-transfers-cuda-cc/

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer as many images with `cudaMemcpy` as you want, but it won't get noticeable faster because the transfer rate is the same, you just skip a little overhead. Also, depending on the image size, this may exceed your GPU RAM.

For 5000 images, if you want to compare every image to every other image, you should check if the calculation in CUDA makes up for the copying time. You identified the bottleneck correct, but in cases like this the copying tends to outweigh potential acceleration of parallel computing, unless the comparison itself is very expensive.

To copy large chunks of images at once, you have to store them in a continuois chunk of memory. A simple (but also a little error-prone) way to do so is to store them in a large array of integers. Let's say we have 5 RGB images with 100*100px. 10000 px per image with 3 colors is 30.000 values per image. So, for 5 images, we need to store 150.000 values.

```
int numberOfValues = 150000;
int size = numberOfValues * sizeof(int);
int *images = new int[numberOfValues];
// load 5 images into the array

int *deviceImages;
cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceImages, size;
cudaMemcpy(deviceImages, deviceImages, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

The code for 100 images is exactly the same except for the number of values, but as noted, you may run into memory problems, depending on your image and RAM size. If your images have 1000*1000 pixel which is a little more realistic, for 100 images (and three colors), you would need 300.000.000 int values, translating to a 1,2GB chunk of RAM with 4 byte integers.

Depending on your images, you could also use `char` instead of `int`, which would decrease the size by 4.